# How to loop non-numeric objects?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Here is a sample of my function.

```
function_x<- function(t=4){
  col1<- col2<- numeric(length=t+1)
  col1[1]<- col2[1]<- 1
  for(step in 1:t){
    col1[step+1]<- col1[step]+1
    col2[step+1]<- col2[step]+3
  }
  out<- cbind(col1,col2)
  return(out)
}
function_x()
```

The output is as follows:

```
     col1 col2
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4   10
[5,]    5   13
```

How would one script the code of this loop function so that the output of `col1` would be seen as it is below?

```
      col1 col2
[1,]    c1    1
[2,]    c2    4
[3,]    c3    7
[4,]    c4   10
[5,]    c5   13
```

Many thanks in advance.

*** UPDATE ***

The answer given by @Roland is helpful and answers the question asked efficiently. However, the question asked here is not an actual reflection of the difficulty that I am facing. I thought that I may be able to work the answer into the code; my lack of experience does not allow me to do so.

Below is the more relevant code to my problem:

```
function_x<- function(t=9,m=0.009,n=100){
  col1<- numeric(length = t+1)
  col2<- numeric(length = t+1)
  col1[1]<- 1
  col2[1]<- n

  for(step in 1:t){
    col1[step+1]<- col1[step]+1
    col2[step+1]<- rbinom(1,col2[step],1-m)
  }
  out<- cbind(col1,col2)
  return(out)
}
```

Which gives the following:

```
      col1 col2
 [1,]    1  100
 [2,]    2  100
 [3,]    3   99
 [4,]    4   98
 [5,]    5   97
 [6,]    6   97
 [7,]    7   94
 [8,]    8   93
 [9,]    9   93
[10,]   10   92
```

How can the code be written so that the results show:

```
      col1 col2
 [1,]   a1  100
 [2,]   a2  100
 [3,]   a3   99
 [4,]   a4   98
 [5,]   a5   97
 [6,]   b1   97
 [7,]   b2   94
 [8,]   b3   93
 [9,]   b4   93
[10,]   b5   92
```

Where a particular condition is met in `col1`, as seen in `[5,]`, the sequence will change to `b1` in this case.

Comment: `data.frame(col1 = paste0("c", seq_len(t + 1)), 
           col2 = Reduce("+", rep(3, t), 1, accumulate = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you, Roland. Your answer answers my original question wonderfully. However, the question I asked was not a true reflection of my current problem. I have updated the question. @Roland

Comment: "Where a particular condition is met in col1" What is the condition?

Comment: Where "col1 == a5". I imagine it would look something like `if(col1 == a5){...}`

Comment: So, you want to always increment the letter after every five steps?

Comment: No, in the problem I have the letter is incremented twice, resulting in three letters (a,b,c) with the respective number pasted to it. `a` is incremented to be `b` after the 9th step (`a1:a9`). `b` is incremented to `c` 7 steps after that (`c1:c7`). The sequence of `c` is 6 steps long (`c1:c6`). After `c6` the next step should loop back to `a1`.

Comment: If you cannot explain the rules for increments I can't help you implement it. Right now my best guess is `c(paste0("a", 1:9), paste0("b", 1:7), paste0("c", 1:6))` and then use recycling of this vector, but I'm not confident that's what you actually want.